# ASP.Net Page runs slow at first time If i used System.Web.Ui Namespace

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a web application written in ASP.Net Web Form 4.0 using C#, the production machine is a windows server 2012 R2 with IIS 8.5.9600.16384 and SQL server 2014.

Every Page in the application run fast, but any page using the namespace system.Web.Ui Take nearly 2 minutes when i open it first time, then i can open any page fast without problem, if no one open this page for nearly 25 minutes the problem will return and i need to wait another 2 Minutes To open it again.

Note : This problem only on The production machine i didn't have it on the development machine, on the development machine every thing is okay.and The Problem just when i use the namespace system.Web.Ui not for the first application page or whole application.

I tried to set the idle time out to 0 in the Application Pool like this example [Set idle time out example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18941856/web-app-slow-performance-when-leave-idle-for-some-time/37936965#37936965), every thing will become okay for little hours but after 1 day if there is no any one use the site the problem is returned.

Please help to diagnose and solve this problem.

Front End Code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="WebForm1.aspx.cs" Inherits="WebApplication2.WebForm1" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <h3>TestPage</h3>
</asp:Content>
```

Back End Code:

```
   using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace WebApplication2
{
    public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(),"AlertBox","Alert('Hello World');",true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the code which is written on the page load event? I can see one `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` apart from this.

Comment: This is the Code:
ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this,this.GetType(),"AlertBox","Alert('Hello World');",true);
it just show alert box.

Comment: How many script file it add for that when you write `ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock` on browser. Why some one like to do this. Just put that in java script on you page if it is possible.

Comment: Based on your description the problem is with your web server and not the web application. Generally speaking, a web page of an asp.net web application is slower on first run than in subsequent requests. The delay depends on many things including the code executed on the `Page_Load` event. Since you don't seem to have such code and you don't load anything special such as an IoC container or Entity Framework upon page start-up then what you should really look into is the way IIS is configured. I am pretty sure the `System.Web.UI` and the JavaScript registration are not to blame.

Comment: Does your application connect to a database or something similar?

Comment: शेखर This is an example for code which use (System.Web.Ui Namespace) this happend with me when i write another code use this Name Space for me i use this Namespace for the GridView Binder.

Comment: dpant .. i think like you the problem is not with Web Application, but iam sure it is from the NameSpace System.Web.UI, also i try to use logger, the problem happened before the page load, also i didn't use entity framework.

Comment: Julián .. Yes its connected to database, but i didn't face problem with other site even it use the database.

Answer (score -1):

You can simply use JavaScript alert in your web page instead of WebForm.

```
alert("Your Message");
```

Comment: My problem not with alert, my problem is with the NameSpace System.Web.UI when i used it on the application, i need this Namespace with Gridviewbinder not just for the alert.